# using delay in python makes the code jump.how to solve it?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, delay

I am using python to create an User interface application. I am using tkinter for the UI. I created three widgets (two buttons and a label). when a button is pressed i want to excecute a method which has the following tasks to be done in an order.

- update button name in the label
- change button colour to red(initially it will be black)
- play an audio file until n seconds
- change back the colour to black

here is how i coded this.

```
from ttk import *
from Tkinter import *
from pygame import *
import time
root=Tk()
n=2
global cmajorBox
global dmajorBox
mixer.init()
def cMajor1():
    currentChordVariable.set("C MAJOR")    #l1
    cmajorBox.config(bg = "red")           #l2
    print 'c major'                        #l3
    mixer.music.load('c major.mp3')        #l4
    mixer.music.play()                     #l5
    time.sleep(n)                          #l6
    cmajorBox.config(bg="black")           #l7
def dMajor1():
    currentChordVariable.set("D MAJOR")
    dmajorBox.config(bg="red")
    print 'd major'
    mixer.music.load('d major.mp3')
    mixer.music.play()
    time.sleep(n)
    dmajorBox.config(bg="black")

cubeFrame=Frame(root)
cubeFrame.grid(row=1,column=1)
cmajorBox =Button(cubeFrame,text="cmajor",bg="black",
                  fg="white",padx=5.5,pady=20,command=cMajor1)
cmajorBox.grid(row = 1, column = 1)
dmajorBox = Button(cubeFrame,text="dmajor",bg="black",
                   fg="white",padx=5.5,pady=20,command=dMajor1)
dmajorBox.grid(row = 1, column =2)

currentChordVariable=StringVar()
currentChordDisplay = Label(root, 
                        textvariable=currentChordVariable,bg="red", 
                        fg="white",padx=70,pady=50)
currentChordDisplay.grid(row=2, column=1)
mainloop()
```

n denotes how long the audio should be played.it is a delay for the next code to start.i have mentioned the line numbers in the code. the code goes on like this while running(l3,l4,l5,l6,l1,l2,l7).i don't know why this happens. the colour change and name update is processed only after the delay even if i coded it before the delay.how to overcome this issue.
this is just a small part of my total application.i am using 24 buttons like this.i am stuck with this now.please help.

Comment: The two global statements at the top are useless btw,

Comment: Try calling `root.update()` **after** the line you labelled as "`#l2`". Those lines do run just fine in the correct order obviously, but may not yet be visible on screen until the GUI decides to update.

Comment: thank you dude, the problem was solved.thank you for your valuable sugessions.@ Dennis Soemers

Comment: thank you dude, i realised it.@ SitiSchu

Answer (score 0):

The first two lines of code in that function modify parts of the GUI, but these modifications are not immediately visible on-screen; they'll only become visible when the GUI updates. Because this code is in a function that runs when a button is pressed, it runs in the same thread as the internal Tkinter code (which normally regularly refreshes the GUI). This means the entire function has to complete running before Tkinter's `mainloop()` is able to update the GUI again, and make your changes visible.

In order to force the GUI to update manually, you can use `root.update()` after the lines of code that modify parts of the GUI. The complete function would then look as follows:

```
def cMajor1():
    currentChordVariable.set("C MAJOR")    #l1
    cmajorBox.config(bg = "red")           #l2
    root.update()
    print 'c major'                        #l3
    mixer.music.load('c major.mp3')        #l4
    mixer.music.play()                     #l5
    time.sleep(n)                          #l6
    cmajorBox.config(bg="black")           #l7
```